# Deduping mySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

A programming error lead to multiple insertions of identical rows in this table.  I am aware that constraints in the schema could prevent the insertions.

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to find a way to delete all but the newest (highest id) row for each round/number pair.  I could definitely script this but I wondered if there is a way to do this in pure SQL?

Comment: It is mySQL 5.1.70-cll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally you can do:

```
delete from your_table
where id not in 
(
    select max(id) from your_table
    group by user, round, date, number
)
```

In MySQL you can't delete from the same table you are selecting from. But you can trick MySQL with another subquery like this:

```
delete from your_table
where id not in 
(
   select * from 
   (
      select max(id) from your_table
      group by user, round, date, number
   ) x
)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the lesson!

Comment: Please note that two (or more) records could share the same MAX value.

Comment: Correct. BTW: there would also be a problem if `id` is a nullable datatype (which it is probaly not)

Comment: what is X here @jerrygarciuh

Comment: @saikiran: `x` is an alias name for the subquery. You need to name every subquery and I chose `x` as name.

Comment: @juergend i think it will work without naming subquery also. i mean i have tried suqueries before and i haven't seen this approach.